# Node.js/sequelize : Accessing the result of findOne() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, sequelize.js

I'm new to node.js, and I try to retrieve a password from a user in a database which contains (username,password) couples. The findOne function seems to return one result, but when I try to access password I always have 'undefined' as a result. Can someone help me with this please ?

Here is the really simple server.js :

```
var express     = require('express');
var app       = express();
var sqlite    = require('sqlite3');
var port      = process.env.PORT || 8000;

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize("_databaseName_", "_username_", "_password_", {
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: "users.sqlite"
});

var User = sequelize.define('User',
{
  tx_index: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true},
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  password: Sequelize.STRING
},{
  timestamps: false,
  tableName: 'data',
  freezeTableName: true
})

//no need of sync, as the db already exists and is populated
//User.sync();

User.findOne({where: {username: 'julien'}}).then(function(user) {
   if (!user) {
    console.log('unknown user');
   } else {
    console.log('user password is '+user.password);
    //console.log('user password is '+user.get('password'));
   }
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('listening => http://localhost:' + port);
```

And the output :

```
node server.js
listening => http://localhost:8000
Executing (default): SELECT `tx_index`, `username`, `password` FROM `data` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`username` = 'julien' LIMIT 1;
user password is undefined
```

If I choose another user name :

```
User.findOne({where: {username: 'WHATEVER'}}).then(function(user) {
```

I have on output :

```
node server.js
listening => http://localhost:8000
Executing (default): SELECT `tx_index`, `username`, `password` FROM `data` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`username` = 'WHATEVER' LIMIT 1;
unknown user
```

So the query seems to be OK, but I can't access the password (undefined).

Finally, the content of the database :

```
SELECT * FROM 'data' LIMIT 0,30;
TX_INDEX    PASSWORD    USERNAME
2           123456      julien
3           titi        toto
4           bar         foo

SELECT tx_index, username, password FROM data WHERE username = 'julien';
TX_INDEX    USERNAME    PASSWORD
2               julien          123456
```

I'm going mad on finding what I have done wrong !

::EDIT::

When I print the wole user object "console.log(user);", here is the output. What is it ? An instance of the 'User' model, but it's empty ?

```
Instance {
  dataValues: {},
  _previousDataValues: {},
  _changed: {},
  '$modelOptions':
   { timestamps: false,
     instanceMethods: {},
     classMethods: {},
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: true,
     underscored: false,
     underscoredAll: false,
     paranoid: false,
     rejectOnEmpty: false,
     whereCollection: { username: 'julien' },
     schema: null,
     schemaDelimiter: '',
     defaultScope: {},
     scopes: [],
     hooks: {},
     indexes: [],
     name: { plural: 'Users', singular: 'User' },
     omitNul: false,
     tableName: 'data',
     sequelize:
      Sequelize {
        options: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        dialect: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        modelManager: [Object],
        connectionManager: [Object],
        importCache: {},
        test: [Object],
        queryInterface: [Object] },
     uniqueKeys: {},
     hasPrimaryKeys: true },
  '$options':
   { isNewRecord: false,
     '$schema': null,
     '$schemaDelimiter': '',
     raw: true,
     attributes:
      [ 'tx_index',
        'username',
        'password',
        'generation',
        'reserved1',
        'modified',
        'created',
        'next' ] },
  hasPrimaryKeys: true,
  __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
  isNewRecord: false }
```

Comment: Try printing the whole `user` object once. The actual user object might be nested inside some result object.

Comment: I can see what seems to be an instance of the model User, but not sure what it is...Seems that I misunderstood something in the use of Promise 'user'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the issue : my database table didn't have any column id, which seems to be important for sequelize. So I add it, even if I don't use it, and it works, without modifying the source code above.